# Connection String for MS SQL Server 2008 using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

MS SQL Server and the web application are both on the same machine.

In `web.config`, I have:

```
connectionString="
   Server=COMPUTER_NAME\MSSQLSERVER;
   Database=MyDatabase;
   Integrated Security=true"
name="ApplicationServices"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I created a new Windows user account named `MyWebsite`. This account is assigned to application pool and my web application is using it.

In SQL Server Management Studio:

- MyWebsite account is added in Security -> Logins
- MyWebsite account is added in MyDatabse -> Security -> Users.
- db_owner option is checked

In SQL Server Security Manager, all protocols are allowed.

I'm still getting the following error message:

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server'
 Error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Problem was in external class library - Linq to SQL is using different connection string in app.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the instance name when you're connecting to the default instance.

Just use COMPUTER_NAME for the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier in the long run if you just use localhost instead of the server or instance name for your connection settings.